# Regarding views and UISegmented Control

Tags: objective-c

I have questions regarding the views. Right now i have created a view controller(root view) which has table view in it. Click on the cell will take to the detail view where i have UISegmented control with four options. Clicking on any of the segmented control button, the data is loaded according to the selection(i have switch statement, which loads the table view data according to it). All these are working fine.

The question is:
For example consider i have four UISegmented buttons - A, B, C, D. Click on A will load a table view with some data- Clicking a particular cell in A view should take me to a different view with some different content in it. Likewise click on B will load a table view with some data - clicking on a particular cell in B view should load a different view.

As this is a UIsegmented control, i can't use each button to connect it to a different view. I was wondering whether i can do it programmatically writing code.

Can anyone answer me whether i can do it programmatically ?

I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do whatever you want when a particular segment is pressed. First you register to receive notification when a segment of your `UISegmentedControl` is pressed like this:

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(segmentPressed:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

You can also do the equivalent in Interface Builder if you prefer. Then in your action you would do something like:

```
- (IBAction)segmentPressed:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentControl *segmentControl = sender;

    if (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        // Do whatever you want when the first segment is selected
    } else if (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        // Second segment selected
    }
    // ....
}
```